# I need a button to perform a multiplication of two inputs (one has a dropdown menu with percentages) and deliver the result in a <p> , with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a button to perform a multiplication of two inputs (one has a dropdown menu with percentages) and deliver the result in a

, with javascript.
I have these inputs to insert a number of tickets and choose a category, and when pressing the summary button, the javascript code performs the following count.
Cantidad x Categoria (each category has a discount of 80%, 50%, 15%)
x the input value =200.

I just started to study javascript and this is part of a job that I have to do. Apologies in advance for the ignorance.

```js
var entrada = 200

function resumen (){
var cantidad = parseInt (document.getElementById("cantidad").value);
var categoria = parseFloat (document.getElementById("categoria").value);
if (cantidad > 0){
let resultado = (cantidad*categoria)*entrada; 

}

}
```

```html
     </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p style="text-align: left">Cantidad</p>
          <input
            id="cantidad"
            type="number"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Cantidad"
            aria-label="Cantidad"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p style="text-align: left">Estudiante</p>
          <select
            id="categoria"
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
          >
            <option value="0.8">Estudiante</option>
            <option value="0.5">Trainee</option>
            <option value="0.15">Junior</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="col">
        <p 
        id="resultado"
        
        style="background-color: aquamarine;"
        class="m-0"   
        >Total a pagar</p>
        
      </div>

      <br />
      <!-- Poner dos botones, Borrar y resumen-->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button
            style="
              width: auto;
              color: white;
              background-color: rgb(128, 204, 52);
            "
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-success container-fluid justify-content-center"
          >
            Borrar
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button
            id="resumen"
            onclick=""
            style="
              width: auto;
              color: white;
              background-color: rgb(128, 204, 52);
            "
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-success container-fluid justify-content-center"
          >
            Resumen
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask], and revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question and not just state your lengthy requirements.

Comment: change the title of your post and add a question instead. Like, how can I perform multiplication with two buttons?

Comment: Sorry, this was my first question, I didn't know how to do it right. Now I add the question in the post and not only in the title.

Answer (score 0):

@zer00ne explained a few concepts very well and I agree with his recommendation to link the calculation to the `input` event of any of the input fields. However, in case you are still interested in a solution that is based on your HTML, then the following would be a minimalist way of putting your `resumen` button into action:

```js
const price = 200,
 [amount,discount,total,btn]=
   ["cantidad","categoria","resultado","resumen"].map(e=>document.getElementById(e));
btn.onclick=()=>total.textContent=amount.value*discount.value*price
```

```html
     </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p style="text-align: left">Cantidad</p>
          <input
            id="cantidad"
            type="number"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Cantidad"
            aria-label="Cantidad"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p style="text-align: left">Estudiante</p>
          <select
            id="categoria"
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
          >
            <option value="0.8">Estudiante</option>
            <option value="0.5">Trainee</option>
            <option value="0.15">Junior</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="col">
        <p 
        id="resultado"
        
        style="background-color: aquamarine;"
        class="m-0"   
        >Total a pagar</p>
        
      </div>

      <br />
      <!-- Poner dos botones, Borrar y resumen-->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button
            style="
              width: auto;
              color: white;
              background-color: rgb(128, 204, 52);
            "
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-success container-fluid justify-content-center"
          >
            Borrar
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button
            id="resumen"
            onclick=""
            style="
              width: auto;
              color: white;
              background-color: rgb(128, 204, 52);
            "
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-success container-fluid justify-content-center"
          >
            Resumen
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

### If you just want to pass - Example B

Assign classes to everything and bind `<button>` to the "click" event. See [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) on how to manage user interaction.

### If you want an A - Example A

Save the button for another function like sending data or jumping to the next page. Simple calculations can be done immediately upon user interaction.

- Wrap everything in a `<form>`
- Bind `<form id="`X`">` to the "input" event
- Add `.number` class to `<input>` and `<select>`
- Replace `<p>` with  an `<output>` or place an `<output>` within `<p>`
- See [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) and
  [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content) on how to control `<form>` and it's fields.
- See [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) on how to manage user interaction.

***Details are commented in example***

### Example A

```js
// Reference form
const UI = document.forms.UI;

// Bind form to input and change events
document.forms.UI.oninput = discountPrice;

// Set price.value and total.value once
UI.elements.price.value = (200).toFixed(2);
UI.elements.total.value = (200).toFixed(2);

function discountPrice(e) {
  // Reference to all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  // Ensure price.value is always formatted
  IO.price.value = parseFloat(IO.price.value).toFixed(2);
  /*
  If the user entered data into anything with the class .number...
  */
  if (e.target.matches('.number')) {
    /*
    ...get the values of price and discount and turn them into numbers
    */
    let P = +(IO.price.value);
    let D = +(IO.discount.value);

    /*
    If the value of price is greater than 0...
    ...Make the value of total be:
    price.value - (price.value x discount.value) suffix a '.NN'
    */
    if (P > 0) {
      IO.total.value = (P - (P * D)).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='UI'>
  <input id='price' class='number' type='number' min='0' value='200'>
  <select id='discount' class='number'>
    <option value='0'>No Discount</option>
    <option value='.1'>10%</option>
    <option value='.25'>25%</option>
    <option value='.5'>50%</option>
  </select>
  <p><output id='total' class='number'></output></p>
</form>
```

### Example B

```js
const price = document.querySelector('.price');
const discount = document.querySelector('.discount');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const total = document.querySelector('.total');

button.onclick = discountPrice;

function discountPrice(e) {
  total.textContent = parseFloat(price.value) - (parseFloat(price.value) * parseFloat(discount.value));
}
```

```html
<input class='price' type='number' min='0' value='200'>
<select class='discount'>
  <option value='0'>No Discount</option>
  <option value='.1'>10%</option>
  <option value='.25'>25%</option>
  <option value='.5'>50%</option>
</select>
<button class='button'>Total</button>
<p class='total'>200.00</p>
```